# Can I make two procedures that call each other out in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a database to store sales information. I am currently writing two procedures, one to insert new details about a sale, and another one to update an already existing detail. If the user wants to insert an already existing detail, I want my procedure to call the update procedure. Likewise, if the user wants to update a non-existing detail, I want to call the insert procedure. My code to insert a new detail is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure EX1.insert_detail
    (id_sale IN INTEGER, id_product IN INTEGER, qty IN INTEGER)
IS
    id_detail INTEGER;
    mi_seq INTEGER;
    u_price FLOAT;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        select detail.id_sales_order_detail into id_detail from EX1.sales_order_detail detail
            where detail.id_sales_order = id_sale and detail.id_prod = id_product;
    END;
    if id_detail is null then
        select seq_sales_order_detail.nextval into mi_seq from dual;
        select prod.list_price into u_price from EX1.product prod;

        insert into EX1.sales_order_detail values
            (mi_seq, id_sale, id_product, qty, u_price, EX1.calc_discount(qty, u_price));
        BEGIN
            EX1.update_costs(id_sale);
        END;
    else
        EX1.update_detail(id_sale, id_product, qty);
    end if;
END insert_detail;
```

To update a sales detail:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure EX1.update_detail
    (id_sale IN INTEGER, id_product IN INTEGER, qty IN INTEGER)
IS
    id_detail INTEGER;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        select detail.id_sales_order_detail into id_detail from EX1.sales_order_detail detail
            where detail.id_sales_order = id_sale and detail.id_prod = id_product;
    END;
    if id_detail is null then
        BEGIN
            EX1.INSERT_DETAIL(id_sale, id_product, qty);
        END;
    else
        UPDATE EX1.SALES_ORDER_DETAIL
            SET ORDER_QTY = ORDER_QTY + qty
        WHERE ID_SALES_ORDER = id_sale AND id_prod = id_product;
        BEGIN
            EX1.update_costs(id_sale);
        END;
    end if;
END update_detail;
```

I first compiled each procedure without calling the other one. Once I did this, I rewrote the insert procedure to call the update proc. I compiled it and everything was fine. The problem came when I tried to call the insert procedure in my update procedure.

I am getting the following error at the time of compiling: `ex1.insert_detail is invalid`. However, before compiling `ex1.update_detail`, all procedures are valid. Somehow, having each procedure calling the other one is making them both invalid.

Is there anyway I can accomplish this? Or should I just write all code in each procedure without calling the other one?

Any help or guidance in this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you have a cyclic dependency between the two procedures. Compiling an object on which a program depends invalidates that program: cyclic dependency means you're stuck in a perpetual loop of invalidation and recompilation.

One solution is to use a package. Objects depend on the package spec, so providing that doesn't change we can do anything with the package body.

```
 create or replace package pkg_sales as
     procedure insert_detail(id_sale IN INTEGER, id_product IN INTEGER, qty );
    procedure update_detail(id_sale IN INTEGER, id_product IN INTEGER, qty );
end pkg_sales;
```

Then your body can do the referencing like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  package body pkg_sales as

    procedure insert_detail(id_sale IN INTEGER, id_product IN INTEGER, qty IN INTEGER)
    IS
        id_detail INTEGER;
        mi_seq INTEGER;
        u_price FLOAT;
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            select detail.id_sales_order_detail into id_detail from EX1.sales_order_detail detail
                where detail.id_sales_order = id_sale and detail.id_prod = id_product;
        END;
        if id_detail is null then
            select seq_sales_order_detail.nextval into mi_seq from dual;
            select prod.list_price into u_price from EX1.product prod;

            insert into EX1.sales_order_detail values
                (mi_seq, id_sale, id_product, qty, u_price, EX1.calc_discount(qty, u_price));
            BEGIN
                EX1.update_costs(id_sale);
            END;
        else
            update_detail(id_sale, id_product, qty);
        end if;
    END insert_detail;

   procedure update_detail(id_sale IN INTEGER, id_product IN INTEGER, qty IN INTEGER)
    IS
        id_detail INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            select detail.id_sales_order_detail into id_detail from EX1.sales_order_detail detail
                where detail.id_sales_order = id_sale and detail.id_prod = id_product;
        END;
        if id_detail is null then
            BEGIN
                INSERT_DETAIL(id_sale, id_product, qty);
            END;
        else
            UPDATE EX1.SALES_ORDER_DETAIL
                SET ORDER_QTY = ORDER_QTY + qty
            WHERE ID_SALES_ORDER = id_sale AND id_prod = id_product;
            BEGIN
                update_costs(id_sale);
            END;
        end if;
    END update_detail;
end pkg_sales;
```

Cyclic dependency is still bad though. It points to a design flaw. A better solution would be to have one procedure, `procedure manage_detail(id_sale IN INTEGER, id_product IN INTEGER, qty IN INTEGER)` which does the control logic, and decides whether to invoke an insert or update sub-routine accordingly.

Alternatively, for this situation there is the MERGE statement, which handles whether to insert or update (or indeed delete) in pure SQL. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606).

---

> "am I better just writing the code to perform each procedure on its own"

Probably not. You'll end up duplicating some code. Modularity is a good thing, but it's even better to structure your logic to avoid cyclic dependency. Apart from anything else you risk infinite recursion.

Comment: So, am I better just writing the code to perform each procedure on its own, without depending on the other procedure?

Comment: I have expanded my answer with some suggestions.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you very much. But now I do realize that what I was doing was a poor programming solution. I will change it according to your suggestions.

Comment: I vote for the suggestion to use the MERGE statement; that lets Oracle decide whether an insert or an update is needed. And if you decide to stick with the separate insert/update statements, there is no need to perform a select statement first - assuming you have a primary key on the table (and if not, why not?!) - you would just do the insert and if it fails with dup_val_on_index, handle the error in the exception block and do the update instead there. Or, if you're expecting more updates than inserts, perform the update first and only do the insert if the update statement's rowcount was 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use a package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_CIRCULAR_REFERENCE
IS
  PROCEDURE A( value NUMBER );
  PROCEDURE B( value NUMBER );
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_CIRCULAR_REFERENCE
IS
  PROCEDURE A( value NUMBER )
  IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'A: ' || value );
    IF value <= 1 THEN
      NULL;
    ELSIF MOD( value, 2 ) = 0 THEN
      A( value / 2 );
    ELSE
      B( value );
    END IF;
  END;

  PROCEDURE B( value NUMBER )
  IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'B: ' || value );
    IF value <= 1 THEN
      NULL;
    ELSIF MOD( value, 2 ) = 0 THEN
      A( value );
    ELSE
      B( 3 * value + 1 );
    END IF;
  END;
END;
/
```

So your package would be something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EX1.DETAILS
IS
  FUNCTION get_detail_id ( id_product EX1.sales_order_detail.id_prod%TYPE )
    RETURN EX1.sales_order_detail.id_sales_order_detail%TYPE;

  PROCEDURE insert_detail(
    id_sale    IN EX1.sales_order_detail.id_sale%TYPE
    id_product IN EX1.sales_order_detail.id_prod%TYPE,
    qty        IN EX1.sales_order_detail.id_qty%TYPE
  );

  PROCEDURE update_detail(
    id_sale    IN EX1.sales_order_detail.id_sale%TYPE
    id_product IN EX1.sales_order_detail.id_prod%TYPE,
    qty        IN EX1.sales_order_detail.id_qty%TYPE
  );
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need two procedures.
Just do one with a MERGE instead. Something like the following should be a good start;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure EX1.upd_ins_sales_detail(p_id_sale IN INTEGER, p_id_product IN INTEGER, p_qty IN INTEGER)
IS

BEGIN

    MERGE INTO ex1.sales_order_detail sod
    USING (SELECT exist_sod.id_sales_order_detail, exist_sod.id_prod, prod.list_price
           FROM   ex1.sales_order_detail exist_sod
                  INNER JOIN
                  ex1.product prod ON (prod.prod_id = exist_sod.prod_id)
           WHERE  exist_sod.id_sales_order = p_id_sale
           AND    exist_sod.id_prod = p_id_product
          ) upd
    ON    (    sod.id_sales_order_detail = upd.id_sales_order_detail)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET sod.qty = sod.qty + p_qty
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (mi_seq, id_sale, id_product, qty, u_price, EX1.calc_discount(qty, u_price))
                          VALUES (seq_sales_order_detail.nextval,
                                  p_id_sale,
                                  p_id_product,
                                  upd.list_price,
                                  EX1.calc_discount(p_qty, upd.list_price)

    EX1.update_costs(id_sale);

    COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
WHEN ..... THEN
  put an exception as required here

END upd_ins_sales_detail;
```